Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1. OR Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3
I have an older Gradle/Ionic project, and I can't build it.
I have this build.gradle configuration:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

I receive this error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.jar
Required by:
project :CordovaLib

After change to:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

I receive this error:

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar

After change to:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        }
        google()
    }

I receive this error:

Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.jar

I know the problem is in repositories URLs, but I tried a lot of combinations, but without success. Can you help me please?

Does any of the configuration listed here (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.bintray/1.7.3) help?

Hello, yes I tried this configuration. It works for com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3 error, but when I set the configuration for:
maven {url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2"}
jcenter()
I receive error with com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1. When I set it for:
maven {url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
google()
Than com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 is OK, but I receive error for com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3. It's like a vicious circle.

I think maybe you need both?
